# HTML table filter with unique values only

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

I have a 300x11(rowXcolumn) html table that I wanted to filter exactly like Excel or Google Sheets's filter. However, after searching a bit I found out the following code below in a website. This works as I wanted but it has one major problem. It shows same value multiple times. For example in the 2nd column, there are 2 values same "Apple" and 2 whitespaces . In the current code, it displays Apple twice and whitespace twice. However, I want it should show the same values only once. For example, it will show "Apple" only once, and if I select apple it will filter both rows containing apple.
Thank you very much for your help.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table class="grid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td index=0>Name
            <div class="filter"></div>
          </td>
          <td index=1>Address  
            <div class="filter"></div>
            </td>
          <td index=2>City
            <div class="filter"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>first</td>
          <td>first add</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>second</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>SDF hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>SDF hello</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".grid thead td").click(function(){
      showFilterOption(this);
    });
    
});

var arrayMap = {};

function showFilterOption(tdObject){
  var filterGrid = $(tdObject).find(".filter");
  
  if (filterGrid.is(":visible")){
    filterGrid.hide();
    return;
  }
  
  $(".filter").hide();
  
  var index = 0;
  filterGrid.empty();
  var allSelected = true;
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="all" type="checkbox" checked>Select All</div>');
  
  var $rows = $(tdObject).parents("table").find("tbody tr");
  
  
  $rows.each(function(ind, ele){
    var currentTd = $(ele).children()[$(tdObject).attr("index")];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("grid-item")
    var str = $(ele).is(":visible") ? 'checked' : '';
    if ($(ele).is(":hidden")){
      allSelected = false;
    }
    div.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" '+str+' >'+currentTd.innerHTML;
    filterGrid.append(div);
    arrayMap[index] = ele;
    index++;
  });
  
  if (!allSelected){
    filterGrid.find("#all").removeAttr("checked");
  }
  
  filterGrid.append('<div><input id="close" type="button" value="Close"/><input id="ok" type="button" value="Ok"/></div>');
  filterGrid.show();
  
  var $closeBtn = filterGrid.find("#close");
  var $okBtn = filterGrid.find("#ok");
  var $checkElems = filterGrid.find("input[type='checkbox']");
  var $gridItems = filterGrid.find(".grid-item");
  var $all = filterGrid.find("#all");
  
  $closeBtn.click(function(){
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $okBtn.click(function(){
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item").each(function(ind,ele){
      if ($(ele).find("input").is(":checked")){
        $(arrayMap[ind]).show();
      }else{
        $(arrayMap[ind]).hide();
      }
    });
    filterGrid.hide();
    return false;
  });
  
  $checkElems.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  $gridItems.click(function(event){
    var chk = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    $(chk).prop("checked",!$(chk).is(":checked"));
  });
  
  $all.change(function(){
    var chked = $(this).is(":checked");
    filterGrid.find(".grid-item [type='checkbox']").prop("checked",chked);
  })
  
  filterGrid.click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  
  return filterGrid;
}
```

**style.css**

```
table thead tr td{
  background-color : gray;
  min-width : 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.filter{
  position:absolute;
  border: solid 1px;
  top : 20px;
  background-color : white;
  width:100px;
  right:0;
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone else will fix that limited JS for you but otherwise use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). It has all you want with extensive documentation, and it's a popular plugin so it's not hard to find any answers to questions you might have about it. Here's an example with everything you desired in your post:

```js
/* Range Search - https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var min = parseInt($('#min').val(), 10);
  var max = parseInt($('#max').val(), 10);
  var age = parseFloat(data[3]) || 0;

  if (
    (isNaN(min) && isNaN(max)) ||
    (isNaN(min) && age <= max) ||
    (min <= age && isNaN(max)) ||
    (min <= age && age <= max)
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Init dataTable - Options[paging: off, ordering: off, search input: off] */
  var table = $('#table').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "ordering": false,
    dom: 'lrt'
  });

  /* Column Filters */
  $(".filterhead").each(function(i) {
    if (i != 4 && i != 5) {
      var select = $('<select><option value="">Filter</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(this).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var term = $(this).val();
          table.column(i).search(term, false, false).draw();
        });
      table.column(i).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
      });
    } else {
      $(this).empty();
    }
  });

  /* Range Search -> Input Listener */
  $('#min, #max').keyup(function() {
    table.draw();
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.1/datatables.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="min" name="min" placeholder="Min Number">
    <input type="text" id="max" name="max" placeholder="Max number">

    <table id="table" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="filterhead">Name</th>
          <th class="filterhead">Address</th>
          <th class="filterhead">City</th>
          <th class="filterhead">Number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>first</td>
          <td>first add</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>second</td>
          <td>as</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>SDF dfd</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>as</td>
          <td>SDF hello</td>
          <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>third</td>
          <td>Apple</td>
          <td>SDF hello</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```